# Need to add another onClick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox, that is styled using onclick handler.

The issue I have is , I also want to fire a div simultaneously.. to display hidden message.

Kind of like: checkbox ( tick to go featured )

If ticked show featured div, else hide.

Code I have is:

```
<span id="checkboxWrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input name="include" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" class="styledCheckbox" /></span>
```

Wanted to also fire the div like...:

```
onClick="toggle('feature');"
```

Can I chain onClick events to one click handler?

ie..

```
onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this);toggle('feature');"
```

Or am I going round in circles.

Comment: you know I havent tried it lol, I just typed that as an example.... will give it a whirl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally, you should try to start using [unobstrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) which basically means you separate the structure from function by moving your javascript inside a `<script>` tag or into a separate file. So your code would look like this and make it easier to read.

HTML

```
<span id="checkboxWrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap">
  <input name="include" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" class="styledCheckbox" />
</span>
```

Script

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('.styledCheckbox').click(function(){
    setCheckboxDisplay(this);
    toggle('feature');
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use event listeners. They're better anyway. :)

```
var check = document.getElementById('checkbox');

check.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setCheckboxDisplay(this);
});

check.addEventListener('click', function () {
    toggle('feature');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can call multiple statements in the `onclick` attribute as long as they are semicolon-delimited.  That gets unweildy though, so I'll usually define a new function to wrap the two into one call.

Answer (score 1):

Just delegate this to a function that does all your work...

```
// Somewhere in the head of the file...
function doOnClickStuff(target) {
    toggle('feature');
    setCheckboxDisplay(target);
}
```

And then just have the onClick handler invoke that...

```
onClick="doOnClickStuff(target);"
```